# Custom tick is not displaying on edge/ie for checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have tried several attempts to make the ticks the same as other browsers, but it is never the same for edge. Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/skb643ez/

This is the structure of my HTML:

```
<p>
Test
<a href="/somewhere">Somewhere (link)</a>
</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="test"><label for="test">Test label</label>
<p>
 Test
<a href="/somewhere">Somewhere (link)</a>
</p>
```

the images on chrome is like this
[image: chrome checkbox]

meanwhile on Edge
[image: edge checkbox]

I tried ms-checked or ms-expand display none, but this does nothing. I think it's because the webkit-appearance is not working. Is there any solution without using js or jquery? Thank you

Comment: i tried using ::ms-check just now, its actually works to change the background to fully red, however, the tick after doesn't change to the :after i set

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer, we set the background and border-color to transparent for ::-ms-checked. https://jsfiddle.net/ycbvz4tl

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
   background-color: transparent;
   border-color: transparent;
   color: white;
}
```